# Simple HTML App - Not Found after Server Move?

Tags: html, facebook

I created a Plain HTML/CSS App, uploaded it to my test server. Installed the app etc etc, All worked fine.
When I uploaded the files to my client's server, changed the URL's in the Developers section, it is not showing their websites' 404 page.

I have deleted the app and started again, but still getting this 404 not found page.
If I type the URL to the index.html file on their server, into the browser, it loads fine.

What am I missing here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Make sure the default document is index.html for the application. Also be sure the proper case is being used, and the web browser is not caching the not found pages.

Comment: I have cleared browser cache - still the same. The file is named index.html . Confused why this works fine on one server and not another.